# (NOT USERNAME?) in the toplinks section, cookie issue?

Tags: php, session, cookie, persistent

Sometimes I will see in the top header (NOT MYUSERNAME?) and items that I’ve added in the past in my cart, even know I’m not logged in anymore.  This is extremely annoying and I haven’t seen a fix for this and I’ve experienced this in the past in several shops. It’s mind-boggling how this is happening…

The link goes to something like /unsetCookies/

Comment: What custom modules do you have installed relating to customers? This is not native functionality in Magento...

Comment: I have a custom "group" customer extension.  Forgot to mention in the link it had persistent in it... in my settings I enabled persistent shopping

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the persistent shopping stuff...maybe it is native functionality after all. Have you tried disabling persistent shopping carts? It would at least tell you if that was where it was coming from.

Comment: The cookie/session is random, I'd best testing out multiple solutions if I could. Regardless I will let you know.

Comment: This is not a bug. It's a feature. Disable the persistent shopping cart from `System->Configuration->Persistent Shopping Cart`

Answer (score 2):

This message gets added by the module `Mage_Persistent`. Basically what happens is it listens to the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` and called the function `applyPersistentData`. This function will fire all the Persistent module's custom block, like the one you are seeing via:

```
Mage::getModel('persistent/persistent_config')
        ->setConfigFilePath(Mage::helper('persistent')->getPersistentConfigFilePath())
        ->fire();
```

As far as I am aware all the persistent options can be turned off. The xml path is as follows `persistent/options/enabled` and there is a function in the helper to check this: `Mage::helper('persistent')->isEnabled()`

The whole section can be turned on and off via the admin section under `System->Configuration->Persistent Shopping Cart->General Options->Enable Persistence`

Answer (score 1):

I have to keep the cart persistent and also keep the customer logged in until he logs out, but am also getting the above issue and customer gets logged out automatically. Ideally, it should keep the customers logged in.